# Creating multiplicative interaction variables using R

Tags: r, loops, multiplication

I am trying to write a function that calculates all the multiplicative interactions of the variables I specify. Refer to the code below to get an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
mul <- function(data, vars)
{
for(ii in vars)
 {
  for(jj in vars[ii : length(vars)])
  {
   data[, paste(ii, jj, sep = "mul")] <- 
   data[,  which(colnames(data) %in%   ii)]*data[,   which(colnames(data) %in% jj)]
  }

 }
test   
}
```

Since I am an amateur in R, could some R black belt coders help me out here.

As a data example, I would want the below code to work in the end:

```
data(iris)
x <- names(iris)[1:4]
mul(iris, x)
```

And gives me 4C2 (6) additional variables in my iris data.frame with all multiplicative variables. Finally, I need to do this for a data frame with 70K obs and ~100 variables. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid loops altogether, use `combn`:

```
data(iris)
x <- names(iris)[1:4]
combn(x,2,FUN=function(x) iris[,x[1]] * iris[,x[2]]  )
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]
#[1,] 17.85  7.14  1.02  4.90 0.70  0.28
#[2,] 14.70  6.86  0.98  4.20 0.60  0.28
#[3,] 15.04  6.11  0.94  4.16 0.64  0.26
#[4,] 14.26  6.90  0.92  4.65 0.62  0.30
# etc etc
```

If you want to set the names at the same time, do:

```
iris[combn(x,2,FUN=paste0,collapse=".by.")] <- 
  combn(x,2,FUN=function(x) iris[,x[1]] * iris[,x[2]] )
```

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that this doesn't avoid a loop, it merely hides it (betwixt a whole lot of other crud) inside `combn()`. And, since you're calling `combn()` twice, you've now actually doubled the number of iterations in the algorithm. Bravo.

Comment: @bgoldst - with ~100 variables as per the OP's question, I would consider any loss in computation speed a trade-off for greater readability. There's really no need for sarcasm.

Comment: Fair point, although it could be argued that explicit loops are more straightforward and therefore more readable than calls to `combn()`. But this is a good solution, I apologize for the sarcasm. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do this:

```
data('iris');
head(iris);
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
mul <- function(data, cols ) {
    for (i in 1:(length(cols)-1)) {
        for (j in (i+1):length(cols)) {
            col1 <- cols[i];
            col2 <- cols[j];
            data[,paste(col1,col2,sep='.mul.')] <- data[,col1]*data[,col2];
        };
    };
    data;
};
iris.mul <- mul(iris, names(iris)[1:4] );
head(iris.mul);
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length.mul.Sepal.Width Sepal.Length.mul.Petal.Length Sepal.Length.mul.Petal.Width Sepal.Width.mul.Petal.Length Sepal.Width.mul.Petal.Width Petal.Length.mul.Petal.Width
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa                        17.85                          7.14                         1.02                         4.90                        0.70                         0.28
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa                        14.70                          6.86                         0.98                         4.20                        0.60                         0.28
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa                        15.04                          6.11                         0.94                         4.16                        0.64                         0.26
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa                        14.26                          6.90                         0.92                         4.65                        0.62                         0.30
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa                        18.00                          7.00                         1.00                         5.04                        0.72                         0.28
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa                        21.06                          9.18                         2.16                         6.63                        1.56                         0.68
```

Notes:

- Your use of `ii` in your code is inconsistent; you've set it to iterate over each column name (in `for (ii in vars)`), but also attempted to use it as a numeric index in the `ii:length(vars)` expression. I used `i` and `j` as numeric index variables, and then assigned `col1` and `col2` in the inner loop.
- In order to avoid duplication, you have to iterate the outer loop over all columns *except* the last one, and then iterate the inner loop over all columns from *one after* the current outer iterator all the way to the last one. Thus, in my code `i` goes over `1:(length(cols)-1)` and `j` goes over `(i+1):length(cols)`.
- Not sure what the `test` identifier was at the end of your function; you have to return `data`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my loop function, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The way to create all the 2 way combinations of a vector is to use `combn`:

```
> combn(x, 2)
     [,1]           [,2]           [,3]           [,4]          
[1,] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" 
[2,] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Length"
     [,5]          [,6]          
[1,] "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length"
[2,] "Petal.Width" "Petal.Width"
```

You can then iterate over the columns of that character matrix:

```
comb.names <- combn(x, 2)
for ( i in 2:ncol(comb.names) ){ test <- cbind(test,
    iris[[ comb.names[1,i] ]]*iris[[ comb.names[2,i] ]])
    names(test)[i] <- paste( substr(comb.names[1,i],1,7), 
                             substr( comb.names[2,i],1,7),sep="_")}
 str(test)
#--------------------
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ SepL.SepW      : num  17.8 14.7 15 14.3 18 ...
 $ Sepal.L_Petal.L: num  7.14 6.86 6.11 6.9 7 9.18 6.44 7.5 6.16 7.35 ...
 $ Sepal.L_Petal.W: num  1.02 0.98 0.94 0.92 1 2.16 1.38 1 0.88 0.49 ...
 $ Sepal.W_Petal.L: num  4.9 4.2 4.16 4.65 5.04 6.63 4.76 5.1 4.06 4.65 ...
 $ Sepal.W_Petal.W: num  0.7 0.6 0.64 0.62 0.72 1.56 1.02 0.68 0.58 0.31 ...
 $ Petal.L_Petal.W: num  0.28 0.28 0.26 0.3 0.28 0.68 0.42 0.3 0.28 0.15 ...
#------------------
```

The really quick way to do this ... assuming you are contemplating a regression problem is with that R formula evaluation:

```
lm(as.numeric(Species) ~ (.)^2, data=iris)

Call:
lm(formula = as.numeric(Species) ~ (.)^2, data = iris)

Coefficients:
              (Intercept)               Sepal.Length  
                 4.425390                  -0.792828  
              Sepal.Width               Petal.Length  
                -1.119006                   0.228466  
              Petal.Width   Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width  
                 1.378179                   0.240113  
Sepal.Length:Petal.Length   Sepal.Length:Petal.Width  
                -0.004753                  -0.050226  
 Sepal.Width:Petal.Length    Sepal.Width:Petal.Width  
                -0.017482                  -0.356884  
 Petal.Length:Petal.Width  
                 0.135710
```

Comment: `combn` has a `FUN=` argument to apply a function to the combinations directly, which would avoid the need for looping

Comment: Yes. I would have given you even more quatloos if the SO interface allowed.