# R: How can I combine values from multiple pairs of binary variables into new columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I have a dataframe with 88 observations of 224 binary variables. I want to create new columns by adding together each pairwise combination of these 224 variables = 50176 pairs.

e.g., `df[225] <- df[1] + df[2]`, `df[226] <- df[1] + df[3]`, and so on.

Is there a simple way I could do this with `apply` or a for loop?

Comment: Almost certainly, probably something involving `?combn`. Can you provide a simple example like `df <- data.frame(a=c(TRUE,FALSE),b=c(FALSE,FALSE),c=c(TRUE,TRUE))` or something that is representative.

Comment: Duplicate is for multiplying, not summing, but I think it's close enough as the logic is identical. Just change `*` to `+`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but it's untested. If you need more help/debugging/testing, please provide some sample data.

```
combos = combn(seq_along(df), 2)
new_cols = matrix(NA_integer_, ncol = length(combos), nrow = nrow(df))
for(i in seq_along(combos)) {
  new_cols[, i] = df[[combos[1, i]]] + df[[combos[2, i]]]
}
colnames(new_cols) = apply(
  combos, 2, 
  function(x) paste(names(df)[x[1]], names(df)[x[2]], sep = ".")
)
result = cbind(df, new_cols)
```

Comment: @thelatemail's [combn solution] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382679/17331405) is ok

Comment: I always forget that `combn` has a function argument.